# Проблема вывода RU строк на Linux С++

Tags: c++, linux, windows

Проблема заключается в неправильности вывода строк на Linux. Программу писал на Windows с кодировкой 1251, при запуске этого же кода на Linux появляется совершенно другой вывод, хотя я использую исходный алфавит. Повторюсь ещё раз, программа на Windows работает исправно и всё так, как следует. У меня сейчас 4 программы шифрования, которые исправно работают на Windows и я не могу понять как мне их подправить для корректной работы на Linux. Оставляю код одной из программ и прошу знающих людей объянсить как мне перенести код с Windows на Linux, хотя бы на примере данного кода и по возможности хочу узнать почему и как это работает, чтобы запустить ещё 3 программы на Linux. Так же оставлю ниже вместе с кодом скрин вывода данной программы. Используется шифрование методом Цезаря сдвигом на 1 символ.
PS: Слово "привет" вводится корректно, я проверял. Точно такой же код работает безупречно на Windows. Повторяюсь во избежании быть неправильно понятым. Спасибо :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string encrypt(string input)
{
vector<char> word(input.begin(), input.end());
string alphabet = "aбвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя.,:;-!?1234567890";

for (int i = 0; i < (int)input.length(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (int)alphabet.length(); j++)
    {
        if (word[i] == alphabet[j])
        {
            word[i] = alphabet[(j + 2)];

            break;
        }
    }
}
string str(word.begin(), word.end());
return str;
}


string decrypt(string input)
{
vector<char> word(input.begin(), input.end());
string alphabet = "aбвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя.,:;-!?1234567890";

for (int i = 0; i < (int)input.length(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (int)alphabet.length(); j++)
    {
        if (word[i] == alphabet[j])
        {
            word[i] = alphabet[(j - 2)];
            break;
        }
    }
}
string str(word.begin(), word.end());
return str;
}

int main()
{

setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");

string text;
cout << "Введите данные для шифрования: " << endl;
cin >> text;


string textencrypt = encrypt(text);
cout << "Зашифрованные данные: " << textencrypt << endl << "\n";


cout << "Нажмите Enter для расшифроки данных: " << endl;
getchar();



string textdecrypt = decrypt(textencrypt);
cout << "Расшифрованные данные: " << textdecrypt << endl << "\n";


cout << "Нажмите Enter для закрытия программы: " << endl;

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119). 2. к операционным системам вопрос отношения, конечно, не имеет. он имеет отношение к тому факту, что [utf-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) - кодировка, использующая **разное** количество байт для представления разных символов. 3. дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C+%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы зашифрованный текст в utf-8 тоже состоял из русских букв, то такая реализация  алгоритма работать не будет, поскольку в utf-8 русские буквы занимают 2 байта, а цифры и символы пунктуации 1 байт. (кстати, в существующем виде у вас **ошибка** (не зависимо от кодировки) -- вот тут -- `if (word[i] == alphabet[j])  { word[i] = alphabet[(j - 2)]; ....` при `j < 2` (первые 2 буквы алфавита) **выход за начало массива**)

Comment: Так наоборот на линуксе все шикарно по сравнению с виндой. `setlocale` - в мусор, код пересохраняете в кодировке UTF8, и кодировка всегда нормальная. Правда придется переписать код, потому что кириллица в UTF8 занимает по 2 байта на символ, но это полезное упражнение.

Comment: ещё можно опцию компилятору указать `-finput-charset=cp1251`, тогда gcc перекодирует текст в utf-8

Comment: HolyBlackCat. уважаемый, подскажите пожалуйста как переписать код чтобы работал правильный вывод на UTF-8 ? Конкретнее.

Pavel Gridin, где это вписывается, подскажите пожалуйста.

avp, Да, спасибо за найденную ошибку, раньше стоял сдвиг на 1 символ, экспериментировал

Comment: русские буквы - это не один байтик...

Comment: HolyBlackCat, как бы вы переписали код для шифрования данных в рамках русского алфавита? Хотя до вас написали, что такое работать на UTF-8 не будет. Хотелось бы конкретику уже получить хотя бы от кого то, касательно данной проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Вот несколько шагов, ИМХО, которые могут помочь решить эту проблему:

1. Указать в компиляторе, например: `g++ -o your_program your_program.cpp -std=c++11 -finput-charset=UTF-8 -fexec-charset=UTF-8`.
2. Установить локаль с помощью команды:`export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`.
3. Используйте библиотеку locale:

`#include <locale>`

`std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));`

`std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());`

Этот код устанавливает глобальную локаль с кодировкой UTF-8 и связывает стандартный вывод с этой локалью.

4. Используйте `wstring` вместо обычных строк `string`.